# How can I filter an array of objects in typescript such that only objects that contain an optional key are left (and typescript is aware)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This pertains to typescript with strict null checks. Let's say you have an interface such as:

```
interface Name {
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
}
```

And you have a `Name[]` array.

How can I filter this array in such a way that typescript will know `firstName` exists? Ex:

```
names.filter(name => !!name.firstName).map(name => {
  // inside here, typescript still thinks name.firstName is possibly undefined
  // but it should be aware that we have already filtered out elements with an
  // undefined firstName
})
```

Answer (score 5):

`filter` accepts a function that can be a type guard. Typescript will not infer type guards for a function but you can explicitly define the return type as a type guard:

```
interface Name {
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
}
declare const names: Name[];
names
    .filter((name): name is Name & { firstName: string } => !!name.firstName)
    .map(name => {
        name.firstName.big()
    });
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwLYoN4ChnIzBQDOY6WA-AFzJlSgDmA3PsgDZxkUQ11gMQLXAF9cAEwgJOUFAgD2IMshCYIJWjwDaAXVaqsJNgQB0RdpCgAKKwYgBKWneTASaNcgBkybIWLc1WnomZBFkAF4APmQAQhi7M39yNXtjZBMMOAAHWw8onzSCAgSiUmSsEwAjYEYrVKLQ+1YgA)

Above we define that the `name` parameter will be `Name` but using an intersection we add that `firstName` is required. The syntax is a bit verbose but it works.